# MySQL insert trigger only for new rows

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want a trigger in MySQL which inserts information of table A in table B only if it´s a new entry.

My trigger always inserts all entrys of table A to table B if a new entry in table A was made:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON tableA FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `tableB`
        (
        `id`,
        `active`,
        `created_at`,
        `updated_at`
        )
    SELECT
        `id`,
        `active`,
        `created_at`,
        NOW()
    FROM
        tableA;

END;
```

My problem is, that I have a second trigger which inserts the entrys of tableA after any UPDATE. So I can´t make the id unique. The result should be that tableB is some kind of history for any INSERT and UPDATE statements in tableA

Would be thankfull for any help!

Comment: How do You define a new entry?Do You mean Inserted row but not updated row?

Comment: If a new `tableA.id` will be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are select all rows from `TableA`.  I assume that you intend:

```
INSERT INTO `tableB`(`id`, `active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
    SELECT new.id, new.active, new.created_at, MNW()
```

The more general answer to your question is to add a `unique` constraint on `tableB`.  Assuming that `id` defines a duplicate entry:

```
alter table tableB add constaint unq_tableB_id unique (id);
```

Then change the `insert` to ignore any duplicate inserts:

```
INSERT INTO `tableB`(`id`, `active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
    SELECT `id`, `active`, `created_at`, MNW()
    FROM tableA
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = VALUES(id);
```

If duplicates are still needed when you use `new`, you can combine these:

```
INSERT INTO `tableB`(`id`, `active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
    SELECT new.id, new.active, new.created_at, MNW()
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = VALUES(id);
```

Both these queries assume that `id` is what is used to define a duplicate.

Comment: My problem is, that I have a second trigger which inserts the entrys of `tableA` after any UPDATE. So I can´t make the `id` unique. The result should be that `tableB` is some kind of history for any INSERT and UPDATE statements in `tableA`

Comment: @Michael Info like that belongs in the OP!

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Your answer gave me a good hint by using the `NEW` keyword for my trigger. Thanks. If I get a solution I´ll post an update.

Comment: @Michael . . . The last query doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: gave it a try again and it worked aswell. duno why it didn´t yesterday. was a long day, maybe I did something wrong. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for my problem was based on a wrong usage of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`. Instead I had to use the `NEW` keyword to only process the new data:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON tableA FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO `tableB`
    (
        `id`,
        `active`,
        `created_at`,
        `updated_at`
    )
    VALUES
    (
        NEW.`id`,
        NEW.`active`,
        NEW.`created_at`,
        NOW()
    );
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure if this approach is what you want but if you want to connect a different language with MySql, this might work - it did for me.

```
x = SELECT MAX(id) FROM Forum; //This won't work. It isn't real code
```

This shows the id of the latest row added. If there is an id greater than this after then we know that a new row has been added.

```
While True:
    y = SELECT MAX(id) FROM Forum;
    if y > x:
        x = y //This makes the new largest id the actual largest id
        //make add new row to other table
```

There are tutorial online for connecting programming languages with MySql eg  https://pynative.com/python-mysql-insert-data-into-database-table/. This will allow you to turn my pseudocode into real code.

This code is not actual code, so you can't just copy it but it is pseudocode for what I did.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON tableA FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `tableB`
        (
        `id`,
        `active`,
        `created_at`,
        `updated_at`
        )
    SELECT
        `id`,
        `active`,
        `created_at`,
        NOW()
    FROM
        tableA
WHERE tableA.id=new.id; -- copy only the last line

END;
```